# vim ultisnips adds a delay when left-shifting in visual mode

Tags: vim, neovim, ultisnips

I recently installed the [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin on neovim, and I'm having an issue with it:

When I enable `ultisnips`, when I press `<` in visual mode, there's a delay until my lines are left-shifted, but my right-shifting using `>` works instantly.

If I run `:verbose map <`, I see the following

```
x  <nop>       * :call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()<CR>gvs
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim line 64
s  <nop>       * <Esc>:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim line 62
```

And from what I see, the bindings are coming from the snippet files and they're not my mapping, so I was wondering if there's any way for me fix the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set `g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger`? The default is `<Tab>`. It looks like you've set yours to `<nop>`.

Comment: You're completely right @JakeGrossman, I have `let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = "<nop>"` in my settings (I think it was because it was interfering with something in `coc`), so does that have anything to do with the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: Yes. Do you want to disable mappings for UltiSnips? The `<nop>` isn't the action in this case, it's the mapping itself. So effectively what you've done is map the literal keys `<nop>` to an UltiSnips function.

Comment: Actually now I remember: I added that line because of [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1052#issuecomment-504719268) because it was interfering with `coc`'s tab completion. Do you have any suggestions about what I can do?
And yes, I think I can confirm that if I remove that line from my settings, the left-shifting seems to work fine, but then I can't use TAB to navigate `coc`'s completion menu 

Comment: I tried putting the line in my Vimrc and it gives me an error on startup, saying `E117: Unknown function: UltiSnips#map_keys#MapKeys` 

Comment: You’re right, I didn’t look too close. Really you could just set it to any mapping you don’t use, check out `:h key-codes` to see your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `g:UltiSnipExpandTrigger="<nop>"`.

Line 62 of `ultisnips/blob/master/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim`:

```
exec "snoremap <silent> " . g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger . " <Esc>:call UltiSnips#ExpandTrigger()<cr>"
```

You can see that this does not, in fact, disable a mapping for `g:UltiSnipExpandTrigger`. Instead, it maps the literal keys <kbd><</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to `<Esc>:call UltiSnips#ExpandTrigger()<cr>`.

Vim is waiting once you type <kbd><</kbd> to see if you will then press <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>></kbd>. After waiting a period of time, only then will it shift your selection left (how long depends on the value of `'timeoutlen'`).

What you need to do is set `g:UltiSnipExpandTrigger` to a different key. If you want to disable it, you could map it to a function key between 13 and 19 (you probably don't have it on your keyboard):

```
let g:UltiSnipExpandTrigger = "<F13>"
```